# Question on a function $f$ such that $f: \mathbb R^n \leftarrow \mathbb R^n$,

Tags: real-analysis

Let  $f(x) = x||x||^2$ where $x \in \mathbb R^n$ . Then which is correct?

1. $(Df)(0) = 0$
2. $(Df)(x) = 0$ for all x
3. f is one to one
4. f has inverse.

My attempt:- I found out that $\begin{pmatrix}
                               3x_{1}^2+x_{1}^2  & 2x_{1}x_{2} \\
                               3x_{2}^2+x_{1}^2  & 2x_{1}x_{2}
                               \end{pmatrix}$
is the derivative matrix of the given function. Then option 2 is rejected. I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Is $x \in \mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: I just used n =2 as an example....$x \in \mathbb R^n$

Comment: Hint: Use the inverse function theorem to check the local bijectivity of the function.

Comment: The Jacobian you calculated is not the correct one.

Comment: I calculated for n = 2. If it is wrong please tell me which is correct.

Comment: The entries in the bottom row of the matrix should be other way round.

Comment: Switch the order of appearance in the bottom row of the Jacobian.

Comment: Are you certain the arrow in your question statement is going the right way?

Comment: @Chickenmancer does it matter really?

Comment: @Simone It bugs some people like myself :)

Answer (score 1):

The Jacobian is not exactly right, you just have to switch the order of appearance of the entries in the bottom row; anyway you correctly discarded option 2.

The function describes the vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ times the square of their magnitude, so suppose you have two vectors $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf u$ such that $\mathbf f(\mathbf v)=\mathbf f(\mathbf u)$, so $||\mathbf v||^2 \, \mathbf v = ||\mathbf u||^2 \, \mathbf u $; meaning they are parallel, so continue: do they share direction and magnitude?...

Given $\mathbf f(\mathbf x)$ can you think of a way to get back at $\mathbf x$?